# Is it possible to generate a Visual Studio Code extension with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on adding a new language support to vscode, and I have finished a debugger with C#, but this is modified from the mono-debugger sample provided in vscode document. Now I would like to make a language service, so I would like to know if it is possible to do it with C#?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world
vs code is built by electron so  I think it does not support c#, you must use js as document mention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible if you use an abstraction layer called the [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/). Theoretically, it gives you the freedom to implement language support in any language that supports socket communication. You will still need a VSCode extension in JS that *starts* the language server, but it doesn't need to do much beyond that.

A few examples:

- [Java Language Server implemented in Java](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls)
- [Python Language Server implemented in Python](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server)
- [C/C++ Language Server implemented in C++](https://github.com/cquery-project/cquery)
- [etc.](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/implementors/servers/)

When writing a language server, you will also need a library that actually implements the protocol part of it. Looks like for C# [one already exists](https://github.com/OmniSharp/csharp-language-server-protocol).

Comment: Thanks, so do you mean I still need a JS or TS project that register a command as an entry?

Comment: More or less - check out the client part of the official language server protocol extension sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/lsp-sample/client/src/extension.ts. You would also have to declare settings specific to your language server in package.json and pass them on from the VSCode extension to the server, etc.

Comment: (note that in your case this would have to look slightly different, in the sample the server is also written in TS and it's using the vscode-languageserver-node lib, which is a TS implementation of the protocol)