# Can I create VS Code extensions in Python/C++?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am totally new to creating extensions in VS Code, and all the official examples of extensions are written in Typescript/Javascript, which I have no experience with. Is it possible to create VS Code extensions in other languages, such as Python or C++?

If so, could anyone point me to any resources to get me started?

Comment: No. VSC is an electron app and runs JavaScript. TypeScript needs to be compiled to JavaScript

Comment: @rioV8 thanks, I will mark this as answered.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828638/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-visual-studio-code-extension-with-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by creating a [C++ module for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), which can then be loaded like any other node module. Of course, some glue code written in JS or TS is necessary to register the extension and translate calls to/from vscode.

I've gone this way [in my ANTLR4 extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4), but gave up eventually, because of the troubles I had due to incompatible dependencies (you have to make sure the extension uses the exact same V8 version, which was used to build the underlying Node.js used by vscode, on all supported platforms).

This situation might have change, I don't know, but with that in the background I don't recommend it.

If you want to add support for a new language in vscode you can also write a separate language server, as is mentioned in the linked SO answer. For other type of work, I'm afraid, you have no alternative to use.

Answer (score 0):

No, as @rioV8 said, since VSCode is an electron app and runs on Javascript.